# How to access gcm response notification in ios?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an iphone application using swift , connected app to gcm to receive remote notification . The problem is notification sent with no sound and in the background mode only , when i try to access the response from the gcm server it causes error , the response from gcm is like :

```
[body: Hello World!, gcm.notification.message: Hello World!, gcm.message_id: 0:1468499209627258%406a09df406a09df, message: Hello World!, aps: {
alert = "Hello World!";
"content-available" = 1;
```

}]

Please , how to access body element in this array , and how to make it works on foreground mode , Thanks

Comment: It's not an array. It's a dictionary containing several types of values.

Comment: Ok , I received it in a dictionary but still can not access any key

Comment: Please share also the encountered error that appears in logs.

Comment: Have a look at this sample where the gcm.notification.message value is extracted. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCM/AppDelegate.m#L63